# Laravel Eloquent hasMany filtered by parent table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my system there are users, each of which has holiday allowances each year.

There are 3 tables (simplified):

**users**
- id
- name

**user_leave_allowances**
- id
- user_id
- from
- to
- allowance

**user_leave**
- id
- user_id
- from
- to
- days

In the UserLeaveAllowance model I have set up the following relationship:

```
public function leave(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserLeave','user_id','user_id');
}
```

And retrieving the leave allowance by the following:

```
$leaveAllowance = UserLeaveAllowance::with(['leave'])
->where('user_id',$id)
->get()
```

This pulls in the full list of leave allowances (user_leave_allowances) for that user along with all the leave they have currently requested (user_leave).

However, the allowances will be for different periods of time, e.g. 1/1/2017 - 31/12/2017 and leave will be taken out of these periods. So for each leave allowance period I want just the leave that falls within those two dates (from & to), at the moment it just pulls through all the leave for that user into each leave allowance.

I have tried many different ways around it, using the where conditions on the hasMany as such...

```
public function used(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserLeave','user_id','user_id')
->where('from', '>=', 'user_leave_allowances.from')
->where('to', '<=', 'user_leave_allowances.to');
}
```

and

```
public function used(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserLeave','user_id','user_id')
->whereRaw('user_leave.from >= user_leave_allowances.from')
->whereRaw('user_leave.to <= user_leave_allowances.to');
}
```

But I just can't figure out a way to get this to work. I'm fairly new to Laravel and trying to get to grips with Eloqent and relationships, I'm sure the answer isn't too far away.

Comment: Don't you need to filter the `to` also? `->where('user_leaves.to', '<=', 'user_leave_allowances.to')` ?

Comment: Yes, it would need that in there. Edited to show leave needing to fall within the leave allowances' from & to.

Comment: How do you know how much leave a user is allowed every allowance period? There's no column for that anywhere

Comment: I simplified to columns just to focus on the main issue of getting the right leave for the right allowance periods, that was the major issue. I've updated the tables to show my 'allowance' and 'days' columns that I will be using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

**users**
- id
- name

**user_leave_allowances**
- id
- user_id
- from
- to

**user_leave**
- id
- user_leave_allowances_id
- from
- to

In short relate your leave with your leave allowances rather than the user directly because in essence a leave request is taken out of the allowance not out of the user directly.

```
class User extends Model {
     public leaveAllowance() {
         return $this->hasMany(UserLeaveAllowance::class);      
     }        
} 

class UserLeaveAllowance {
      public user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }
      public leaveRequests() { 
        return $this->hasMany(UserLeave::class);
      }
}

class UserLeave {
      public allowancePeriod() { 
        return $this->belongsTo(UserLeaveAllowance::class);
      }
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
UserLeaveAllowance::whereHas("user", function ($q) { 
        return $q->where("id", <user id>); //Allowances for this user
})->leaveRequests() 
->selectRaw("SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, to, from)) as days")
->value("days");
```

Comment: Really appreciate the response, the only issue I can see is that in the where argument on scopeCurrentAllowance you're using Carbon to get the date for now. What I'm looking for is to list all the allowances for a user (i.e. 2017-2018, 2018-2019, etc) and pull in the leave for that user for each of those periods so I can calculate amount of time used in each allowance period.

Comment: I've updated it. The main point is that your data model will be much easier to manage and much more expressive if you made the user leave related to the leave allowance instead of relating it via the user.